# Files not deleting to Recycle bin from External Hard Drive - Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, external-hard-drive, recycle-bin

I recently realized that deleting files from my Toshiba External drive (E:), deletes permanently instead of going to the Recycle bin (I get the message to "permanently delete the files") Not sure if this just started to happen, but I didn't noticed this before. I would like Windows to delete the files to the (windows) recycle bin, like it does with everything else, including my other external drive from WD (D:)

When right clicking the (windows) recycle Bin properties, I noticed that the drive in question (Toshiba (E:)) doesn't show. I can see my System (C:) and my other external drive WD 2TB (D:), but NOT my Toshiba drive! I guess this is where the problem is!? How can I get this drive to be "recognized" in the recycle bin? I'm guessing this will fix the problem and then, when deleting something, it will go to the recycle bin instead, hopefully.
Attaching a screen shot of the recycle bin Properties and my drives. Thanks in advance!
[Recycle bin properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMaGQ.jpg)
[My 3 drives](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7nXj.jpg)

Comment: Windows doesn't do a 100% job at 'knowing' if a drive is external or internal. It falsely flags the WD as internal. The Toshiba is flagged as external and correctly behaves as such. There are several ways to try and trick windows into seeing your toshiba drive as an internal hdd, all show varying success but i have never tried any myself. I suggest doing a google search and trying what you are comfortable with.

Comment: Do you have a folder named `$RECYCLE.BIN` on the disk? In order to see it you need to enable in Explorer Option the option of "Show hidden f‌iles, folders and drives" and disable "Hide protected operating system f‌iles (Recommended)".

Comment: Thanks Silbee and harrymc. I actually managed to solve this very easily (and luckily..). Since this didn't happen before, I decided to just restart my PC and then all the drives were showing in the Recycle Bin properties! Therefore, the problem was solved! Go figure. Now idea what caused it initially though as I had just started a new session when this problem occurred.. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I was actually able to solve this yesterday just by restarting my PC and then all the drives were showing in the Recycle Bin properties! Therefore, the problem was solved! I have no idea what caused it initially though, as I had just started a new session when this problem occurred.. Maybe it's one of those things that don't have an explanation. If someone sees this and does have an explanation, please, I would love to know. Maybe next time just restarting it might not work..